# ios location tracking. distance, speed, time inconsistencies

Tags: ios, location

I'm using IOS locationManager to track location.  Overall it is working well and I'm receiving distance, speed and seconds on an iterative basis of often 1 reading per second.

One thing I'm noticing on a high level is that the total time does not match up with the total distance well for the expected speed, it is always coming in low.  For instance, walking 1 mile might have an associated time of about 7 minutes.  I would more expect that to be upwards of 20-30 minutes.

Looking through the data, the values all seem reasonable individually, but the sums over a long period just don't make sense.  I'm using BestAccuracy for and getting GPS signals, so I wouldn't imagine that would be off much.

Sometimes there are blips that are wildly off even.  Like 100m distance, in 5 second window, at 2mph walking speed. With these I assume the GPS is just recentering. But that doesn't necessarily mean the rest are 100% gine.  Should these extremes be filtered perhaps?

My code below shows that each is being calculated individually, instead of from each other.  Should I instead use two to calculate the third?  ie time = distance/speed or similar.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    for(int i = 0; i < [locations count]; i++){
       CLLocation *newLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:i];

       // meters will be set on every item but very first location
       CLLocationDistance meters = (oldLocation != nil ? [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation] : 0);

       // seconds since now
       NSTimeInterval howRecent = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

       // seconds since last event, float level seconds with good precision
       double eventDateMilli = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970];
       double oldLocationMilli = [oldLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970];
       NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = fabs(eventDateMilli - oldLocationMilli);

       currentSpeed =  (newLocation.speed < 0 ? 0 : newLocation.speed);

       // we now have meters, currentSpeed, secondsBetween
       //   ie, distance, speed, time

       // save to network, etc, for analysis and summation


       oldLocation = newLocation;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using location services in the background? If so, the issue may be that location services are just turning off. You should set the `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` property of `CLLocationManager` to `NO`. Also, be sure you have the `UIBackgroundModes` key in your Info.plist file with `location` as a value in its array.

Comment: The location services are definitely running in background.  I have a db full data I'm looking at and trying to understand the results.